# Multipart file with document name not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, mockmvc

I am getting this error in test case for following api.

> Required request part 'document' is not present

```
@PostMapping(value = "/testModel/{modelName}", consumes = {
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> testModel(@PathVariable("modelName") String modelName,
            @RequestPart MultipartFile document) {
        
    }
```

following is the test case for above api

```
@Test
@Transactional
void testModel() throws Exception {
    service.save(domainModelDTo);

    FileInputStream fi2 = new FileInputStream(new File("test.pdf"));
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.pdf", DEFAULT_BINARY.toString(), fi2);
    log.debug("file name {}", file.getOriginalFilename()); // test.pdf print in log
    log.debug("file length {}", file.getBytes().length); // 44782 print in log
    mockMvc.perform(multipart(ENTITY_API_URL, domainModelDTo.getName()).file(file)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

I have implemented this from the following link as it is:

https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests

Comment: What is your Utils doing? How it creates MockMultipartFile?

Comment: I have updated code, please check now

Answer (score 0):

In your `MockMultipartFile` the first parameter (*name*) must match the request parameter property (in this case *document*).

So if you change your code to:

```
 MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("document", "test.pdf", DEFAULT_BINARY.toString(), fi2);
```

The problem should be resolved.